# Joomla remove asterisk in registration form

Tags: joomla2.5

Can anyone let me know that how can i remove ( * ) sign in Joomla 2.5 user registration form. ( * ) sign is automatically enabling with require field. I want the field to become require without ( * ) sign. Any help in this regard.

Comment: My suggestion is going to the register file maybe it's register.php and using a text editor search tool and fine all the asterisks in the file. Then delete the appropriate ones.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but you could add to your CSS file:

```
.star{display:none;}
```

Comment: Please let me know location of css file

Comment: Just add it to the css file of your site template.

Answer (score 0):

Add :

`.star{display:none !important;}`

in `template.css`